# How do I include Angular Material components in my TypeDoc?

Tags: angular, typescript, glob, minimatch, typedoc

We already have TypeDoc included in our Storybook project and it works for our own components. We'd like to also have TypeDocs generated for the generic Material components.

I already fiddled around a lot with the `--exclude` argument for the typedoc but somehow I cant get it to work.

So far the entry in the package.json looks like this:
`"typedoc": "typedoc --mode modules --exclude **/*.spec.ts* --out build/typedoc --json build/typedoc/typedoc.json projects/"`
I tried around by adding `--includeDeclarations` to the statement and modifying the `--exclude` pattern to exclude everything under `node_modules` except `node_modules/@angular/material` but so far to no avail.
For example I tried the pattern:

`**/{node_modules/!(@angular/material)/**,*.spec.ts}`

But I always get errors like

`"/**" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden.`

I've never worked with minimatch or typedoc so far so help is much appreciated.

Any ideas?

## Update:

I was able to solve this by creating a `typedoc.json` file in the same directory as my `package.json`. The typedoc script now is:
`"typedoc --options ./typedoc.json projects/"` and the content of `typedoc.json` is:

```
{
    "out": "build/typedoc",
    "json": "build/typedoc/typedoc.json",
    "mode": "modules",
    "includeDeclarations": true,
    "exclude": [
        "**/*.spec.ts",
        "**/node_modules/!(@angular)/**",
        "**/node_modules/@angular/!(material)/**"
    ]
}
```

Behavior is as expected now.

Comment: I think `--includeDeclarations` is part of what you need. If you don't exclude anything what happens?

Comment: In that case I actually get a JavaScript heap out of memory error. Another attempt I made was to set `--excludeExternals` and setting the `--externalPattern` to all node_modules but material, but still no typedocs get generated for material.

Comment: If I add `--ignoreCompilerOptions` and run with `--includeDeclarations` and without `--exclude`, typedocs for material aswell as for the other content from node_modules gets generated but I can't seen to achieve the generation of exclusively material components.